# How to count the query result on multiple solr cores at once

Tags: search, solr

Using multicore functionality of solr, we implemented multiple cores into one solr instance and each core having some specific information, like one core is stored Hotel's details along with city while another stored details of Events happening over the city and 3rd core stored details about restaurants in the city. There are other parameters so that we created separate cores.

My application is given search by keyword and I want to show list as:

- hotel(numFound)
- Events(numFound)
- Restaurants(numFound)

then user can drill down into his interested thing.

How can we achieve this by querying to all cores and get the result as number of records found(numFound) for each core.

Solr.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<solr sharedLib="lib" persistent="true">
    <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" hostPort="${jetty.port:8983}" hostContext="${hostContext:solr}">
        <core default="true" instanceDir="hotelDetails" name="hotelDetails"/>
        <core default="false" instanceDir="Events" name="Events"/>
        <core default="false" instanceDir="Restaurants" name="Restaurants"/>
    </cores>
</solr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Solr's Faceted search mechanism. [This link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters) will guide you to get the faceted search.

There might be a lot of ways to achieve what you need. Here's my solution

1. First create a custom field called "**type**". Depending upon each core update it's relevant value (e.g For hotelDetails type:hotel) in each document.
2. Do a [distributed search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) using faceting. Add the following command in your search query and you'll get the result as expected.

For distributed search add

> /select?collection=hotelDetails,Events,Restaurants

For faceting

> facet=true&facet.field=type

Check with the following queries. I hope both the query should work.

> http://'localhost':8983/solr/hotelDetails/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr/hotelDetails,localhost:8983/solr/Events,localhost:8983/solr/Restaurants&q=some_query

and

> http://'localhost':8983/solr/hotelDetails/select?collection=hotelDetails,Events,Restaurants&q=some_query

Comment: Thanks buddy for your valuable comment, its great if you elaborate it more

Comment: I configured 3 cores, each for 1 categories (hotelDetails,Events,Restaurants). If I query http://localhost:8983/solr/select?collection=hotelDetails,Events,Restaurants its simply return the 404 error(without append the name of core we can query?). Please let me know, what i missing.. Appreciate your efforts